# ehcache is not working

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, ehcache

Hi I'm implementing annotation based ehcache in my application. I'm implementing this on service layer and I'm using DetachedCriteria for queries, but ehcache is not working. Can anybody have any idea about this? please help me or suggest me some other way to do this.
Thanks in advance

In ehcache.xml

```
    <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" />

    <cache name="loadAll" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />

</ehcache>
```

on service layer I'm using

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="loadAll")
    List<ShiftDetail> loadAll(DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria);
```

and in applicationContext.xml ehcache is mapped as

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven  create-missing-caches="true" cache-manager="cacheManager" />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" >
            <property name="configLocation"  value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Maybe you could show your code? I've done a little with ehcache, but I can't regurgitate it like it's the alphabet. Consider clicking **edit** on your question and adding some of the relevant code and configuration. This will give us some context and something to work with. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Raman, did you solve the problem? I've your same issue and I'm a little bit on pain. Every time I call a metodh it doens't create a cache instance. This is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194982/spring-annotation-cache-cachedecoratorfactory-not-configured-for-defaultcache

Comment: what exactly do you want to cache?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have done the following steps.
1. You need a **ehcache.xml** file with proper configuration.Sample can be found [here](http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xml)
2.In your springapplicationcontext.xml see whether you have added correct **xsd** in the beans tag.
Sample correct configuration is show below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
     http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring 
     http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.2.xsd
     ">
<cache:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/xml/spring/ehcache.xml" /> 
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Now in your method use the `@Cacheable` of `import com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable;`

This is from my app and it should work.